# AndEngine, box2d and Galaxy Tab issue

Tags: android, box2d, gravity, andengine, galaxy-tab

I'm developing a physics game using AndEngine with box2d physics engine. I have a cross-like figure with 12 vertices with a physics body, created using a triangulation algorithm. There are two forces applied to it: the gravity and the anti-gravity, which compensates the gravity. I've tested this game on different devices: HTC Hero, Samsung Galaxy I9000, Motorola Milestone and Galaxy Tab P1000. All the devices except Tab have no problems with dealing with the figure, but Tab behaves rather weird, the figure just flies away very fast, and also when there are another figures in the world, they share this strange behavior. Did anyone have issues with testing physics games on Galaxy Tab? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FarmTower runs well on the Galaxty Tab P1000 and uses Physics too.
I've been hearing of someone talking about a weird threading model on that device.

Does it act predictable when you disable your antigravity?

Comment: No, I've made some tests, and antigravity is not the problem. I think, the problem is that it does not recognize the coordinates of the body vertices properly. I've written a method that translates sprite coordinates to body, and I feel it does not work with cross.